# Probability of event on Poisson process arrival

Tags: probability-distributions

I have the following problem:

A mail server, sends emails with rate $7.5/\text{hour}$.

What is the probability that it will send exactly $5$ emails in one hour?

To solve it, I did the following using a Poisson distribution:

$$\frac{7.5^5 e^{-7.5}}{5!}$$

or with sage math:

```
def dpoi(x):
  return (7.5^x * (e^-7.5)) / factorial(x)

dpoi(5) 
0.109374594682555$$
```

is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Hey @Eckhard. You should read it http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/6883/asking-questions-with-very-short-answers?cb=1 you can add your comment as answer and I do accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested I repeat my comment as an answer:

Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mere generalization of Eckhard's answer.

If $X \sim Poisson(\lambda)$, then the pdf of $X$ is $P(X=k)=\frac{e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{k}}{k!}$, and this is the same as asking 'what is the probability that exactly $k$ events happen in a given time interval'

Comment: thank you for improving the knowledge base :-)